# How to automatic PoPup JqModal after process

Tags: jquery

I want to ask. How to get automatic pop up automatic after do something..

```
if ($a!=NULL)
<a href="javascript:$.modaldialog.error('<?php echo $result; ?>');">Success</a>
<pre class="prettyprint">
$.modaldialog.error('');
</pre>
else
<a href="javascript:$.modaldialog.error('<?php echo $result; ?>');">Failed</a>
<pre class="prettyprint">
$.modaldialog.error('');
</pre>
```

but in that case. We must click succes first. I want to automatic without click that. and directly out the popUp.
Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you could fix the indentation of the code so it is easier to understand?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do here but you can open it automatically on page load like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery().ready(function($){

      $('#jqModal').jqmShow();

});
</script>
```

or if you are trying to get a status back from a php page first and show a message based on the response something like:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: "var1=value1"
}).done(function( msg ) {
  //logic for message here
  $('#jqModal').jqmShow();
});
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

jQuery().ready(function($){

      $('#jqModal').jqmShow();

});
</script>

i want to write text= 'success'
can u help me? how do this that your script below.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you pass in a message:

```
<div id="jqModal" class="jqmWindow" style="display: none;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery().ready(function($){

$('#jqModal').jqm({onShow:setText}); 
$('#jqModal').jqmShow();

function setText(){
   $('#jqModal').text("success");
}


});
</script>
```